# Let $T$ be the linear operator on $P_1(R)$ deﬁned by $T(p(x)) = p'(x)$. Let $\beta = \{1,x\}$ and $\beta' = \{1+x,1−x\}$. Find $[T]_{\beta}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be the linear operator on $P_1(R)$ deﬁned by $T(p(x)) = p'(x)$, the derivative of $p(x)$. Let $\beta = \{1,x\}$ and $\beta' = \{1+x,1−x\}$.

How can I find $[T]_{\beta}$?

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Where does $\beta'$ come in?

Comment: What have you learned about finding the matrix for a linear transformation with respect to a given basis (or bases)?

Comment: @user1337 I know that $[T]_\beta=[[Tv_1]_\beta, [Tv_2]_\beta]=[[T(1+0x)]_\beta, [T(0+1x)]_\beta]=[[(0x+0)]_\beta, [(0x+1)]_\beta]=\begin{bmatrix}?&?\\?&?\end{bmatrix}$. But would it be $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Halfway through that computation, you switched the order of $\beta$ from $1,x$ to $x,1$. I think user1337 has the right idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your attempt, you are almost there.

You have that $T(1) = 0 = 0 + 0x = (0,0)_{\beta}$ and $T(x) = 1 + 0x = (1,0)_{\beta}$. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
[T]_{\beta} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

However I think the exercise asks for the matricial representation $[T]_{\beta}^{\beta'}$ instead of $[T]_{\beta}$.

If this is the case, $T(1) = 0 = (0,0)_{\beta'}$ and  $T(x) = 1 + 0x = (1/2,1/2)_{\beta'} $.

Consequently,
\begin{align*}
[T]_{\beta}^{\beta'} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1/2\\
0 & 1/2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

If you could double-check the problem setting, it would be easier to help you.